# MySql showing only default databases

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to list all databases through the code in c# from MySql server.

Altough i am only getting default databases like (performance_schema,information_schema,mysql,sys) not whose I created myself.

```
public static List<string> getDBS()
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();

        string query = "SHOW DATABASES;";
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

        connection.Open();
        MySqlDataReader Reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            string row = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < Reader.FieldCount; i++)
                row += Reader.GetValue(i).ToString() + ", ";
            result.Add(row);
        }
        connection.Close();
        return result;
    }
```

How do I get access, or how do I list them all(within databases created by me)?

Comment: This shouldn't happen... :(

Comment: Silly question: Have you made sure that you've actually created a new database on your MySQL server? If so, is your connection string connecting to the correct server?

Comment: What do you get from SHOW GRANTS on this account?

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner...
`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*81F5E21E35407D884A6CD4A731AEBFB6AF209E1B' WITH GRANT OPTION
GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION`
result for show grants.. Yeah i am sure i've created that database, and also that i am connecting to that server.

Comment: Oh guys sorry, i realized i changed port 3306 which is default i suppose, to 3307 and forgot about it , when i changed it to 3307 in code, i got exception "SSL connection not supported" therefore in MySql string builder i had to set SSLMode property to none! Thank you guys for your replies.